# How to implement breadth-first search for tree structure

Tags: java, recursion, graph, tree

This is the problem that I am trying to solve:

https://dmoj.ca/problem/dmopc14c1p5

The problem mentions that it requires breadth-first search to be solved. However, I do not know how to implement such a search method for this specific problem. Would I require recursion? I have looked other similar questions on Stackoverflow, but none of them helped me understand the problem.

The solutions online all create separate classes for the search method, but since I am submitting the solution to an online grader, I do not think such a solution would work.

All I have right now is the code to collect input for the problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

        int y = kbd.nextInt(); //number of rows
        int x = kbd.nextInt(); //number of columns
        int initX = kbd.nextInt(); //initial starting position
        int initY = kbd.nextInt();
        int endX = kbd.nextInt(); //ending position (main office)
        int endY = kbd.nextInt();

        String [] maze = new String [y];

        //Collect all strings
        for (int i = 0; i < maze.length; i++) 
        {
            maze[i] = kbd.next();
        }

        char [] [] symbols = new char [y][x];

        //Split the strings into chars and insert into symbols 2D array
        //Letter O represents blank space and X represents wall
        for (int i = 0; i < maze.length; i++)
        {
            char [] temp = maze[i].toCharArray();
            for (int j = 0; j < symbols[0].length; j++)
            {
                symbols[i][j] = temp[j];
            }
        }

        //Collect teleporting device coordinates
        int tel = kbd.nextInt();
        int [][] telLocat = new int [tel][2];

        for (int i = 0; i < tel; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                telLocat[i][j] = kbd.nextInt();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the Wiki page?  There basically ain't no other way.  You need those classes or you won't be able to search properly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49589783/java-how-to-implement-breadth-first-search-for-tree-structure

Comment: Is there another way to solve this problem without using breadth-first search?

Comment: Most likely the online grader handles multiple classes if you submit them in the same file. Use inner classes?